Build image with buildpacks from procfile with github actions
So I just migrated from Cloud Shell-Google Cloud to build a docker image.
What I did and was worked fine is with this simple command:
pack build my-app-image --builder gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1 --path .

While my Procfile is simply this:
web: uvicorn main:app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=${PORT:-8080} --app-dir ./src

Where --path . is my current repository project that has been pulled with git pull.
How to construct workflows.yaml for github actions?

name: Build and Deploy with Buildpacks

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main  # Trigger the workflow on push to the main branch
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main  # Trigger the workflow on pull requests to the main branch

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Install Pack CLI
      run: |
        sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cncf-buildpacks/pack-cli
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get install pack-cli

    - name: Log in to Docker Hub
      uses: docker/login-action@v2
      with:
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

    - name: Build and push Docker image using Buildpacks
      run: |
        pack build ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/my-image --builder gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1 --path .
        docker push ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/my-image:latest

For rust language, I use this:
name: Rust - Buildpack

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

env:
  CARGO_TERM_COLOR: always

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      
    - name: Install Pack CLI
      uses: buildpacks/github-actions/setup-pack@v5.0.0
    
    - name: Log in to Docker Hub
      uses: docker/login-action@v2
      with:
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
    
    - name: Build and push Docker image using Buildpacks
      run: |
        pack build ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/rust-rocket-buildpacks --buildpack docker.io/paketocommunity/rust --builder paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-full --path .
        docker push ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/rust-rocket-buildpacks:latest

